# How can I add autoplay to this this Slice Slider?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a slider here and I cannot figure out how to implement the autoplay functionality. Can I set this up quickly in the var settings?

I tried to fill in the `setInterval(spin, 3000);` command before and after the `init` lines but so far it didn't work out.

```
(function($) {

 $.fn.sliceSlider = function(options) {       
    var settings = {  
        speed : '500',
        easing : 'cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.2, 1)',

    };

    if(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    return this.each(function() {   

        var $this = $(this),
            $rightColumn = $this.find('.slice-slider-right-column'),
            $rightWrapper = $this.find('.slice-slider-right-column .slice-slider-wrapper'),
            $rightSlide = $this.find('.slice-slider-right-column .slice-slider-slide'),
            $length = $rightSlide.length,
            $settings = settings,
            mousewheelFinish = 0,

            $leftColumnContent = "";

        $rightSlide.each(function(){
            $leftColumnContent = '<div class="slice-slider-slide">'+$(this).html()+'</div>' + $leftColumnContent;
        });
        $('<div class="slice-slider-left-column"><div class="slice-slider-wrapper">'+$leftColumnContent+'</div></div>').insertBefore($rightColumn);
        if($length>1) $this.append('<div class="pagination"><div class="point active"></div>'+'<div class="point"></div>'.times($length-1)+'</div>');

        var $leftWrapper = $this.find('.slice-slider-left-column .slice-slider-wrapper'),
            $leftSlide = $this.find('.slice-slider-left-column .slice-slider-slide');

        $leftSlide.filter(':last').addClass('active').prevAll().addClass('prev');
        $rightSlide.filter(':first').addClass('active').nextAll().addClass('next');

        $this.find('.slice-slider-wrapper, .slice-align-animation').css({'transition':'all '+$settings.speed+'ms '+$settings.easing, '-webkit-transition':'all '+$settings.speed+'ms '+$settings.easing});

        function init(){
            setActiveSlice($leftWrapper, $leftSlide.filter('.active').index());
            setActiveSlice($rightWrapper, $rightSlide.filter('.active').index());

        }

        function setActiveSlice(foo, index){
            foo.css({'top':$this.height()*(-1)*index});
        }

        init();
        $('.rotate').css({'width':$('.rotate:visible').parent().height()});

        $this.on('mousewheel', function(event) {
            if(!mousewheelFinish && !$('body').hasClass('min-height')){
                mousewheelFinish = 1;
                setTimeout(function(){mousewheelFinish = 0;}, $settings.speed);
                if(event.deltaY>0) {
                    $leftSlide.filter('.active:not(:last-child)').removeClass('active prev next').addClass('prev').next().removeClass('prev next').addClass('active');
                    $rightSlide.filter('.active:not(:first-child)').removeClass('active prev next').addClass('next').prev().removeClass('prev next').addClass('active');
                    $this.find('.pagination .point.active:not(:first-child)').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
                }
                else {
                    $leftSlide.filter('.active:not(:first-child)').removeClass('active prev next').addClass('next').prev().removeClass('prev next').addClass('active');
                    $rightSlide.filter('.active:not(:last-child)').removeClass('active prev next').addClass('prev').next().removeClass('prev next').addClass('active');
                    $this.find('.pagination .point.active:not(:last-child)').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
                }
                init();
            }
        });

        $this.find('.pagination .point').on('click', function(){
            $(this).parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var index = $this.find('.pagination .point').filter('.active').index(),
                activeSlideLeft = $leftSlide.eq($length-1-index),
                activeSlideRight = $rightSlide.eq(index);

            $leftSlide.removeClass('active prev next');
            $rightSlide.removeClass('active prev next');

            activeSlideLeft.addClass('active').prevAll().addClass('prev');
            activeSlideLeft.nextAll().addClass('next');

            activeSlideRight.addClass('active').prevAll().addClass('prev');
            activeSlideRight.nextAll().addClass('next');

            init();
        });
```

I would like to have the slider start when the page is fully loaded...

Comment: Here is the slider: http://mathoma.com/

Comment: The answer is in the documentation: https://github.com/pgooood/sliceslider - `autorun:true` add that to your `settings` var

Comment: Hey and thank you. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work... 

`(function($) {
 
    $.fn.sliceSlider = function(options) {       
        var settings = {
   autorun: 'true',  
   speed : '500',
   easing : 'cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 0.2, 1)',
   
   
  };`


That's what I tried at first, but that didn't solve it.

Comment: You need to take true out of the quotes.

Comment: I did that before I posted this snippet above. Doesn't change a thing though... Still not "autorunning"

Comment: Ah..I looked at the original code for slice slider and it looks like the autorun needs to go into the `extend` method. https://github.com/pgooood/sliceslider/blob/master/jquery.sliceslider.js Look at where autorun is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, if I understood you well, you can easily create a function for that with the code that you already have. Add this code at the end of your snippet:

```
const changeSlide = () => {
  $leftSlide.filter('.active:not(:first-child)').removeClass('active prev next').addClass('next').prev().removeClass('prev next').addClass('active');
  $rightSlide.filter('.active:not(:last-child)').removeClass('active prev next').addClass('prev').next().removeClass('prev next').addClass('active');
  $this.find('.pagination .point.active:not(:last-child)').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

  init();
}

let myAutoplay = setInterval(changeSlide, 3000);
```

Notice that it will stop in the last slider, if you want you can jump and start again from the beginning.

To avoid any issue with your `mousewheel` you just need to clear and set again the interval every time the user interacts with it. Something like this:

```
$this.on('mousewheel', function(event) {
  clearInterval(myAutoplay);
  myAutoplay = setInterval(changeSlide, 3000);
  // The rest of the code
});
```

Hope this help or at least point you to the right direction :)

Comment: Hey and thanks! That one started the animation - which is really nice and a very good hint. BUT unfortunately, it interferes with the scrolling. So when u reach the last section and you scroll back it immediately jumps to the last image again, because of the running autoplay...

Even if there is a way of reversing the animation when reaching the last step, the scrolling still wouldn't work...

Comment: Hi, you just need to clear and set again the interval, I had updated the code above.